# Calculate contract end date in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

is there a work around towards calculating the accurate contract end date for a closed deal in Salesforce?  We have a field which calculates the contract end date based on the `[ Revenue_Date__c + ( Contract_Length__c * 30) ]` , however, this is based on the assumption all months have 30 days, is there a work around this to get a more accurate contract end date?
We are on a Professional edition of Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it will be very tricky to do it with functions/formulas. You could start experimenting with this thing that finds the end of current month:

```
DATE(
    YEAR(TODAY()),
    MONTH(TODAY()),
    CASE( MONTH(TODAY()),
        1, 31,
        2, IF( MOD( YEAR(TODAY()), 4) = 0, 29, 28),
        3, 31,
        4, 30,
        5, 31,
        6, 30,
        7, 31,
        8, 31,
        9, 30,
        10, 31,
        11, 30,
        12, 31,
        DAY(TODAY())
    )
)
```

You could try calculating the difference between days and the end of this year, next year etc (depending on the contract length) but it will be a very nasty solution. And I cry a little every time I see home-grown date handling "library"...

Can you move the logic to apex? In a simple "before insert, before update" trigger it'd be very easy:

```
for(My_Object__c o : trigger.new){
    o.Contract_End_Date__c = o.Contract_Start_Date__c.addMonths(o.Contract_Length__c);
}
```

In "before" trigger you get save to DB for free as a bonus ;) So essentially same as users would see it if it's a formula field.

Comment: I'v got to something like this, however, it now gives an error that it's too big to compile as it's reached its limit of 5000 character                                                        TEXT(IF(DAY (Revenue_Date__c )==1,(DAY( DATE( (YEAR( Revenue_Date__c )+(MONTH( Revenue_Date__c )+ Contract_Length__c )/12) , (MOD((MONTH( Revenue_Date__c )+ Contract_Length__c ),12))+1 ,1) -1)),(DAY( Revenue_Date__c )-1))) &"/"&TEXT(MOD((MONTH( Revenue_Date__c )+ Contract_Length__c ),12))&"/"& TEXT((YEAR( Revenue_Date__c )+FLOOR((MONTH( Revenue_Date__c )+ Contract_Length__c )/12)))

Comment: weirdly, this formula field works well on the DE edition, but when I create the same formula field in our professional edition, i get the error.

Comment: Really weird. Common trick to reduce formula size it to use shorter "API names" for the fields (say `RevDate__c`) - you could still have nice full names on the labels :(